# Proxmox mail gateway installation

Tags: gateway, proxmox

I am trying to install proxmox mail gateway, and I installed that inside a virtual machine as separate iso file downloaded from proxmox official website, and the installation is done now how to open that, in which browser I have to open that, in my root os browser or what , because in that virtual box environment I have installed the proxmox mail gateway and not any browsers.
Please help in this and explain how proxmox mail gateway works.

Installation is finished, now how to open and use that?

Answer (score 0):

Type in your browser:
https://192.168.100.50:8006

But replace 192.168.100.50 with your VM ip.

https://pmg.proxmox.com/pmg-docs/pmg-admin-guide.html#pmg_install_iso

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).